# How to align text and button by bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a text and button which are align by bottom.
Like [image]

I've typed something like this (BTW I am using bootstrap3)

```
123 <button class ="btn btn-default btn-lg ">123</button>
```

However, it seems align by the center of button, I've created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xy9x3xjz/2/) to illustrate my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap by default `vertical-align` is middle you need to change it to bottom with !important as bootstrap css is already having defines `vertical-align` property

Use `vertical-align:bottom !important;` to `button`

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
button{
  vertical-align:bottom !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
123 <button class ="btn btn-default btn-lg ">123</button>
```

Comment: It's work! Thanks, BTW how do you put this runnable snippet?

Comment: I thought it didn't need `!important`

Comment: you need here because same property is also there in bootstrap.css...but if you are writing in a way that i would call after bootstrap.css then no need of !important

Answer (score 1):

Default value for `vertical-align` property is `baseline` i.e all `inline` and `inline-block` elements are aligned according to the `baseline` of the parent element.

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) about Vertical Align css property.

You can change this behavior by setting `vertical-align: bottom` explicitly in styles of Bootstrap's `.btn` class as shown below:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.btn-default {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
123 <button class ="btn btn-default btn-lg ">123</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
a.btn-lg{
padding: 10px 16px 0;
}
```